# How to retrieve values from YII configuration and create custom parameters in configuration?

Tags: yii, configuration

How to retrieve values from yii 2.0 configuration and create custom parameters in configuration? Is there any legal way?

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/index.html gives no information, I could not find configuration class

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your config file add:

```
$params = array_merge(
    require(__DIR__ . '/params.php'),
    ......
    //more here if needed
);
```

Then make file `params.php` here and add:

```
<?php
return [
    'adminEmail' => 'admin@example.com',
];
```

To use params do:

```
Yii::$app->params['adminEmail']
```

Ofcourse with `use Yii` namespace.